# Ant is not working in Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2

Tags: eclipse, ant, java, tools.jar

My problem is that my simple build script who will just print a message is not working in Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2. The Script is given below-

```
<target name="greetings">
<echo>
         Eclipse!
</echo>       
</target>
```

When I tried to execute this script, it is not giving me any error but not printing the message 'Eclipse!'. Also it is not terminating the script, it is continuously in running mode, I have to manully stop it. My project is pointing to 'JDK1.6.0_32' not JRE. All the necessary jars like 'tools.jar' is there. Please let me know why it is happening.

---

Hi, Thanks everybody for the reply. Yes it is there , the full script is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Test" default="greetings" basedir="."> 
<target name="greetings"> 
<echo> Eclipse! </echo> 
</target> 
</project>
```

But still the same problem. It is not showing anything. May be problem is somewhere else in configuration. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

- an ANT script should contain the **root element** `<project/>`.
- `<project/>` contains an attribute called `default` which points to the default target to be executed.
- It is not mandatory to have `default` attribute. But it is mandatory to have at least one target. your script should look like this.

  ```
  <project default="greetings">
  <target name="greetings">
  <echo>
  Eclipse!
  </echo>       
  </target>
  </project>
  ```

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the reply. Yes it is there , the full script is-<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="BMO" default="greetings" basedir=".">
 
    <target name="greetings">
    <echo>
             Eclipse!
        </echo>    
    </target>
</project>

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Yes it is there , the full script is-

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <project name="Test" default="greetings" basedir="."> 
    <target name="greetings"> 
    <echo>
     Eclipse! 
    </echo> 
    </target> 
    </project>
     

But still the same problem. It is not showing anything.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Yes it is there , the full script is- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project name="Test" default="greetings" basedir="."> <target name="greetings"> <echo> Eclipse! </echo> </target> </project> But still the same problem. It is not showing anything

Comment: how are you trying to run the script??

Comment: what is the output on console?

Comment: ".. But it is mandatory to have at least one target. .." => wrong !  A valid ant script only needs <project> ... </project> nothing else, no (default) target, no name and basedir.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="asdc" default="greetings" basedir=".">
    <target name="greetings">
     <echo>
     Eclipse!
     </echo>       
    </target>
</project>
```

It is running good.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Yes it is there , the full script is-

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <project name="Test" default="greetings" basedir="."> 
    <target name="greetings"> 
    <echo>
     Eclipse! 
    </echo> 
    </target> 
    </project>
     

But still the same problem. It is not showing anything.

Comment: Are you doing ?

Right click on the xml- > Run As -> Ant Build - > Targets - > Select "greeting" -> Run

Comment: Yes but nothing will be displaying.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, no error output and not running.

What I did was playing a little with the JRE configuration in "External Tools Configuration...", there are three options "Run in the same JRE as the workspace", "Execution environment" and "Separate JRE".

Changing it from "Execution environment" to "Run in the same JRE as the workspace" solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What's your Eclipse version and your OS ?
Do you use the ant version eclipse ships with or did you edit the Ant_HOME settings via
 `Window | Preferences | Ant | Runtime | Ant Home Entries` ?

a simple script like that should work out of the box :

```
<project>
 <echo>Howdie :-)</echo>
</project>
```

Please check your `workspace/.metadata/.log` file for errormessages.